# How to set a object's field using another objects field in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm trying to set **boxes'** elements copied from **medicineBox's** values like below. Can anyone help me in this. I need to post medicineOrder model to the controller

```
            <tr th:each="medicineBox : ${medicine.medicineBoxes}">
                <td class="text-center">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{boxes[__${medicineBoxStat.index}__].boxNumber}" th:value="${medicineBox.box.number}" />
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" th:text="${medicineBox.medicineCount}"></td>
                <td><input type="number" th:field="*{boxes[__${medicineBoxStat.index}__].medicineCount}" class="form-control" /></td>
            </tr>
```

I'm using two object here -

1. medicine and medicineOrder

------------------> Controller method to get the page

```
    @GetMapping("/{medicineId}")
    public String loadMedicineDetailPage(@PathVariable("medicineId") long medicineId, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("medicine", service.getMedicineById(medicineId));
        model.addAttribute("medicineOrder", new MedicineOrder());
        return WebPages.MEDICINE_DETAIL.toString();
    }
```

------------------> thymeleaf html page

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Spring Boot Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br/>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" th:href="@{/mvc/medicine/list}">Back</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h3 class="text-center alert alert-success">Medicine Details</h3>
    <form class="row g-3" action="#" th:action="@{/mvc/medicine/sell}" method="post" th:object="${medicineOrder}">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" style="background-color:#95edea" disabled class="form-control" id="name" th:field="${medicine.name}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="company" class="form-label">Company</label>
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="company" th:field="${medicine.companyStringName}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="price" class="form-label">Price</label>
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="price" th:field="${medicine.price}"/>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="count" class="form-label">Count</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="count" th:field="${medicine.count}"/>
        </div>-->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="volume" class="form-label">ML</label>
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="volume" th:field="${medicine.volume}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="purchaseDate" class="form-label">Date Purchased</label>
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="purchaseDate" th:field="${medicine.purchaseDate}"/>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="boxNo" class="form-label">Box Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="boxNo" th:field="${medicine.boxNumber}"/>
        </div>-->
        **<input type="hidden" th:field="*{medicineId}" th:value="${medicine.medicineId}"/>**
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr class="table-primary">
                <td>Box Number</td>
                <td>Medicine Count</td>
                <td>Sell Count</td>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="medicineBox : ${medicine.medicineBoxes}">
                <td class="text-center">
                    **<input type="text" th:field="*{boxes[__${medicineBoxStat.index}__].boxNumber}" th:value="${medicineBox.box.number}"** />
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" th:text="${medicineBox.medicineCount}"></td>
                <td><input type="number" th:field="*{boxes[__${medicineBoxStat.index}__].medicineCount}" class="form-control" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---------------> Controller method to handle the post request

```
    @PostMapping("/sell")
    public String sellMedicine(@ModelAttribute MedicineOrder medicineOrder, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            // error handling
        }
        service.sellMedicine(medicineOrder);
        return "redirect:/mvc/medicine/list";
    }
```

----------------> Class MedicineOrder

```
package com.example.demo.dto;

import com.example.demo.model.Box;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MedicineOrder {

    private long medicineId;
    private List<OrderedBox> boxes = new ArrayList<>();

    public long getMedicineId() {
        return medicineId;
    }

    public void setMedicineId(long medicineId) {
        this.medicineId = medicineId;
    }

    public List<OrderedBox> getBoxes() {
        return boxes;
    }

    public void setBoxes(List<OrderedBox> boxes) {
        this.boxes = boxes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MedicineOrder{" +
                "medicineId=" + medicineId +
                ", boxes=" + boxes +
                '}';
    }
}

package com.example.demo.dto;

public class OrderedBox {

    private String boxNumber;
    private int medicineCount;

    public String getBoxNumber() {
        return boxNumber;
    }

    public void setBoxNumber(String boxNumber) {
        this.boxNumber = boxNumber;
    }

    public int getMedicineCount() {
        return medicineCount;
    }

    public void setMedicineCount(int medicineCount) {
        this.medicineCount = medicineCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderedBox{" +
                "boxNumber='" + boxNumber + '\'' +
                ", medicineCount=" + medicineCount +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Not able to get the **MedicineOrder.medicineId** and **medicineBorder.boxes[*].boxNumber** from template to model object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of searching I didn't find any answer which is solving the issue only using **thymeleaf**.
To solve this issue I had to add two hidden input field for *medicineId* and *boxNumber* on *medicineOrder* object and populate those input field using **javascript** as below. Anyway if anyone find the solution by only using thymeleaf, please let me know.

Populated those fields using javascript

```
<script>
    function function__02__number__assignment(_element){
        var __element = _element.children[0];
        var __tElement1 = __element.children[0];
        var __tElement2 = __element.children[1];
        // Copy value from 2 to 1
        __tElement1.value = __tElement2.value;
    }
    function function__01__box_traverse(){
        var rootElement = document.getElementsByClassName('box-stock-details');
        for(var __i=0 ; __i < rootElement.length ; __i++) {
            function__02__number__assignment(rootElement[__i]);
        }
        function_01_01_medicineId();
        return true;
    }
    function function_01_01_medicineId(){
        var _00_1_id_src = document.getElementById('00-1-id-src');
        var _00_1_id_dest = document.getElementById('00-1-id-dest');
        _00_1_id_dest.value = _00_1_id_src.value;
    }
</script>
```

updated template file

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Spring Boot Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br/>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" th:href="@{/mvc/medicine/list}">Back</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h3 class="text-center alert alert-success">Medicine Details</h3>
    <form class="row g-3" action="#" th:action="@{/mvc/medicine/sell}" method="post" th:object="${medicineOrder}">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" style="background-color:#95edea" disabled class="form-control" id="name" th:field="${medicine.name}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="company" class="form-label">Company</label>
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="company" th:field="${medicine.companyStringName}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="price" class="form-label">Price</label>
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="price" th:field="${medicine.price}"/>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="count" class="form-label">Count</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="count" th:field="${medicine.count}"/>
        </div>-->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="volume" class="form-label">ML</label>
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="volume" th:field="${medicine.volume}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="purchaseDate" class="form-label">Date Purchased</label>
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="purchaseDate" th:field="${medicine.purchaseDate}"/>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="boxNo" class="form-label">Box Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="boxNo" th:field="${medicine.boxNumber}"/>
        </div>-->
        <!-- Hidden input to get the value of medicineId from Medicine object -->
        <input id="00-1-id-src" type="hidden" th:value="${medicine.medicineId}"/>
        <!-- Hidden input to set the medicineId on MedicineOrder object  -->
        <input id="00-1-id-dest" type="hidden" th:field="*{medicineId}" />
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr class="table-primary">
                <td>Box Number</td>
                <td>Medicine Count</td>
                <td>Sell Count</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="box-stock-details" th:each="medicineBox : ${medicine.medicineBoxes}">
                <td class="text-center">
                    <input hidden th:field="*{boxes[__${medicineBoxStat.index}__].boxNumber}" />
                    <input disabled class="form-control" type="text" th:value="${medicineBox.box.number}" />
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" th:text="${medicineBox.medicineCount}"></td>
                <td><input type="number" th:field="*{boxes[__${medicineBoxStat.index}__].medicineCount}" class="form-control" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="return function__01__box_traverse()">Sell</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    function function__02__number__assignment(_element){
        var __element = _element.children[0];
        var __tElement1 = __element.children[0];
        var __tElement2 = __element.children[1];
        // Copy value from 2 to 1
        __tElement1.value = __tElement2.value;
    }
    function function__01__box_traverse(){
        var rootElement = document.getElementsByClassName('box-stock-details');
        for(var __i=0 ; __i < rootElement.length ; __i++) {
            function__02__number__assignment(rootElement[__i]);
        }
        function_01_01_medicineId();
        return true;
    }
    function function_01_01_medicineId(){
        var _00_1_id_src = document.getElementById('00-1-id-src');
        var _00_1_id_dest = document.getElementById('00-1-id-dest');
        _00_1_id_dest.value = _00_1_id_src.value;
    }
</script>
</html>
```